# Iconify Icon Not Rendering

Tags: html, css, web, icons

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nino</title>
        <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.7/iconify.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="icons">
                <span class="discord" data-icon="logos:discord" data-inline="false"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have this HTML but the rendered page is completely blank. The icon is not showing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot this class `iconify`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nino</title>
        <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.7/iconify.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="icons">
                <span class="discord iconify" data-icon="logos:discord" data-inline="false"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the icon you should add **iconify** class to the parent element as well:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nino</title>
        <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.7/iconify.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="icons">
                <span class="discord iconify" data-icon="logos:discord" data-inline="false"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```